# Canon CanoScan 9000F Mark II with Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: 14.04, canon, scanner

I can't get my Canon CanoScan 9000F Mark II to work on ubuntu 14.04 64bit.

```
sane-find-scanner
```

and

```
sudo sane-find-scanner
```

both produce:

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x190d [CanoScan]) at libusb:001:018
```

Typing

```
scanimage -L
```

and 
    sudo scanimage -L

both produce:

```
device `pixma:04A9190D' is a CANON Canoscan 9000F Mark II multi-function peripheral
```

Typing

```
scanimage -T
```

and 
    sudo scanimage -T

both cause the scanner to come to life and both produce

```
scanimage: scanning image of size 638x877 pixels at 24 bits/pixel
scanimage: acquiring RGB frame, 8 bits/sample
scanimage: reading one scanline, 1914 bytes...  PASS
scanimage: reading one byte...      PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 2 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 4 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 8 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 16 bytes...    PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 32 bytes...    PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 64 bytes...    PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 128 bytes...   PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 256 bytes...   PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 512 bytes...   PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 1024 bytes...  PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 2048 bytes...  PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 2047 bytes...  PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 1023 bytes...  PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 511 bytes...   PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 255 bytes...   PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 127 bytes...   PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 63 bytes...    PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 31 bytes...    PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 15 bytes...    PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 7 bytes...     PASS
scanimage: stepped read, 3 bytes...     PASS
```

But when I try to do

```
xsane
```

or

```
sudo xsane
```

they both produce a window saying "no devices avaliable".

There was no entry in

```
/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules
```

for Canon CanoScan 9000F Mark II but there was an entry for Canon CanoScan 9000F, so I changed the second value of this entry to match the 9000F Mark II

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="190d", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
# Canon CanoScan 9000F
```

I also edited

```
/etc/sane.d/pixma.conf
```

to include the lines

```
usb
usb 0x04a9 0x190d
```

But nothing has worked. As those of you who actually understand this stuff will probably have worked out, I'm just fishing in the dark and really don't know what I'm doing! :) Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.